# Unable to resize(decrease) home partition in Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: partitioning, live-usb, gparted

This question has been asked a lot but,i didn't find a single answer that could help me
I run Ubuntu 19.10 from a 64GB USB2.0 pendrive. 
I have distributed the partitions as such : 
**home : 49GB**
**snap : 2GB** 
**root : 10GB**

Today when i checked the disk manager i found out that i had used up 86.5% of root partition.
What i want to do now is allocate 10GB of home partition to root one .So,the new partitions will be as follows :

**home : 39GB**
**snap : 2GB** 
**root : 20GB**

But,when i open Gparted/Disks ,select the partition and then click on the resize option,i receive the [following error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ObJPa.png) :

**Error unmounting/dev/sdb6: target is busy (udisks-error-quark, 14)**
I am not aware of which information to hide. So,in the screenshot provided ,i have censored some parts

**What i tried to do before asking this question :** 
I restarted the computer and took note that no other file was open before trying to resize the partition .

**If you want any other information to solve my problem. Do let me know.**

Comment: **First mistake**... running from a flash drive... **Second mistake**... partitioning it into /home and /... **Third mistake**... trying to change partitioning from a live system. You must boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB to use `gparted`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change partition size of partitions that are in use. To repartition a drive, start a live session using an installation USB or DVD. Live sessions come with gparted pre-installed.

Comment: OK , seems good. Does this risk any data loss though ?

Comment: Of course, there is always a risk. Have a good backup of your user data anytime when proceeding to repartitioning. Then, in the worst case, it is only the operating system you loose, but that is nothing: they come for free in various flavors and get better every day. Your data, on the other hand, once lost is lost forever.

Comment: thanks. I followed the instructions and have successfully completed what i wanted, The only problem i face now is that the OS booting time has increased significantly . It takes about 1.5 minutes to start. Do you think it's because of a mistake i have made or it could be because of my bad setup of hardware  ?

Comment: the partition looks something like this now. (root = 32GB)(home = 28GB)(swap = 2GB)